# Are there videos of the highly-skilled fast online players (e.g. GM Andrew Tang) showing their mouse skills?

Tags: online-chess, bullet-chess, chess-videos

It's impressive watching players like GM Andrew Tang play ultra bullet and puzzle rush at super-fast speeds without it being a complete mess.  I'm curious as to how they do it.  When I try, I physically can't move fast enough (I tend to do better on a touch screen): I can't envisage how it's possible to move so fast.

**Question**: Are there videos of the highly-skilled fast online players showing their mouse skills?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=andrew+tang+mouse

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are several.

As stated by @B.Swan, you can search for "Andrew Tang Mouse Speed". Here are a couple videos that come up.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGvgXH_SQtU
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EwP2nFbYm5c
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nSyv0IY6gg

Another GM that comes to mind is Daniel Naroditsky, a well known chess streamer.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pndmSw4Wq6Q